# Retrieve Server Data from a mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have question about how i shall do this.
First i have taken out a list from a mysql database which.

What I want to do is to be able to click on one of these items in the list so that I can get the underlying facts for this particular item.

Now i want to use this as a link to get one row from the database.

The database is done and the list i can see in a website but i dont get the last part to work

show_all_symbol.php

```
//This show the list
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t1_symbolism ";
$q = $pdoconn->query($sql);
$q ->setfetchmode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>  
<table>
<head>        
<tr><th>Symbol</th><th>Alternativtnamn</th> <th>Symboltyp</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
<?php while ($row = $q->fetch()): ?>
<td><img src="<?php echo "/symbol/",$linksbild,($row['symb_type']),"/",($row['symb_pic']); ?>"/></td>
<tr>
<td> <a id="leftside_meny" href= <?php echo "/symbol/show_symbol.php";?> target= "texten"> <?php echo ($row['symb_name']); ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['symb_name_other']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['symb_type']); ?></td>
</tr> 
<?php endwhile; ?>                   
</tbody>
</table>                    
</body>
```

show_symbol.php

```
<body>  
<?php
$funamn = trim($_POST['symbname']);
include 'connect.php';
$sqlanswer = $pdoconn->query(" SELECT * from t1_symbolism where symb_name  '$funamn'");
$row = $sqlanswer->fetch(); 
?>  
<table >
<thead>        
<tr><th>Symbol</th><th>Symbolnamn</th><th>Alternativtnamn</th> <th>Symboltyp</th><th>Fakta</th></tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo "/symbol/",$linksbild,($row['symb_type']),"/",($row['symb_pic']); ?>" width="250" height="250"/></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['symb_name']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['symb_name_other']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['symb_type']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['symb_history']); ?></td>
</tr> 
</table>   
</body>
```

What i want to do is to use this part as Use this part as a clickable link so I can view a record in the table.

```
<td> <a id="leftside_meny" href= <?php echo "/symbol/show_symbol.php";?> target= "texten"> <?php echo ($row['symb_name']); ?></a></td>
```

Thank in the advance!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are looking for a way to pass this value `$row['symb_name']` to this value `$_POST['symbname']`. Here's what i think you should try :

in your show_all_symbol.php

```
<td>
    <a id="leftside_meny" href="<?php echo "/symbol/show_symbol.php?symb_name=" . $row['symb_name'];?>" target="texten">
        <?php echo ($row['symb_name']); ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

in your show_symbol.php

```
$funamn = trim($_GET['symb_name']);
```

If you want to use $_POST then you will have to either figure a way to make a form out of each clickable element and configure it to make a POST or do it using javascript or jquery.

Comment: Hi thanks this solved it but i changed it to =" . $row['id_symb'];?>" then it worked.

Comment: Hi now i it work this part then i have to learn more about GET and POST how they work but thanks. This whas what i needed for now.

Comment: OK cool man, always happy to help...keep learning bro, you'll get way better in time...can you please accept this as the answer in any case to close your question...i've updated the solution to your correction